# Use the definition of the derivative to find $f'(x)$ for $f(x) = x^{3/2}$

Tags: derivatives

Is there anyone who can help me find $f'(x)$ for $f(x) = x^{3/2}$ using the definition of the derivative?

I have tried multiple times but I can't seem to get it right.

Comment: $x^{3/2}$ or $\dfrac{x^3}2$?

Comment: Also, it's useful to include the definition you're supposed to use; common variants being $\lim_{h \to 0}\tfrac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$ and $\lim_{x \to a}\tfrac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}$.

Comment: I have came this far: ( x^3/2 + 3/2xh + h^3/2 ) / h

Comment: Check your algebra, then: binomials with powers other than two don't expand that way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**HINT:**

Note that we can write

$$\begin{align}
(x+h)^{3/2}-x^{3/2}&=\left((x+h)^{3/2}-x^{3/2}\right) \frac{(x+h)^{3/2}+x^{3/2}}{(x+h)^{3/2}+x^{3/2}}\\\\
&=\frac{(x+h)^3-x^3}{(x+h)^{3/2}+x^{3/2}}\\\\
&=\frac{3hx^2+3h^2x+h^3}{(x+h)^{3/2}+x^{3/2}}
\end{align}$$

Now, divide by $h$ and take the limit as $h\to 0$.

Comment: Thank you but in the second row how did you end up with ^3 ?

Comment: You're welcome.  $x^{3/2}\times x^{3/2}=x^3$.

Comment: Thank you again will try it out and let you know if I figured it out!

Comment: You're welcome.  My pleasure.

Comment: Ok so I'm stuck again. After I take the limit as h->0 I've come this far:
( 3x^2 ) / ( 2 * x^3/2 ). How do I continue from this?

Comment: $$\frac{3x^2}{2x^{3/2}}=\frac32 x^{1/2}$$

Answer (score 2):

Here is a long-winded hint.  For $f(x) = x^2$, a key to finding the derivative is algebraically simplifying
$$
    \frac{x^2-a^2}{x-a} = \frac{(x-a)(x+a)}{x-a} = x+a
$$
(when $x \neq a$).
For $f(x)= x^3$, the numerator factors a bit differently:
$$
    \frac{x^3-a^3}{x-a} = \frac{(x-a)(x^2 + ax + a^2)}{x-a} = x^2+ax+a^2
$$
For $f(x) = x^{1/2}$, it's still different:
$$
\frac{\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{a}}{x-a}=
\frac{\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{a}}{x-a}\cdot \frac{\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{a}}{\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{a}}
= \frac{\sqrt{x}^2-\sqrt{a}^2}{(x-a)(\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{a})} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{a}}
$$
You have $f(x) = x^{3/2}$, which is $(x^{1/2})^3$.  Can you combine the previous two approaches?

Comment: That is long winded indeed.

Comment: @MarkViola: Trying to be Socratic. `:-)`

Comment: Then, why not simply use $a-b=\frac{a^2-b^2}{a+b}$ for $a=(x+h)^{3/2}$ and $b=x^{3/2}$?

Comment: That would work too.